# ES Limit Token Count - Token Filter why would we need this?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the latest Elasticsearch document version 5.1, there is a section regarding the Limit Token Count - Token Filter.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-limit-token-count-tokenfilter.html

It has a setting called "max_token_count" which is defaulted to 1.

Maybe I am missing something here but 1 seems way too low.  Why would we need or want to limit the number of max token per document ?

Wouldn't this be affecting the indexing of a very large document ?

Answer (score 0):

The default of 1 token does seem odd, but the max token itself is quite sensible. I'm using it myself, in combination with a unique filter, to limit how searchable some possibly very long user-generated data is.

The field in question is a 'notes' field they can store data in. Data here should only affect relevance, and is not a primary search field, so there's no reason to devote huge chunks of our elasticsearch storage to it.

That said, my current effort to implement this is not respecting the max_token_count parameter, so we'll see how that goes.